Excel cannot find string within formula
I am pulling data from an unstructured data souce with variable number of items per record but I need to process the data in fixed arrays. Anyway, I have parsed each record into a tab "1" "2" "3" and so on.
The sheet I am creating is full of matrix arrays of data and the data is fetched from arrays of data in the worksheet tabs '1' '2' '3' etc. - so there is a massive duplication of arrays of formulae.
I am analyising the data from each record and cross adding for each record.
In each repetition of these arrays I am refrencing the same cell coordinates (such as B3, B4, B5 ... C3, C4, C5 ... etc.
However, they are fetched from different tabs and so after I copy an array, I need to search and replace the worksheet tab names.
So, for example, I need to do search and replace for a block (9 x 16) - 144 elements):
=IF('1'!B$3="","n/a",'1'!B$3)   ...  =IF('1'!J$3="","n/a",'1'!J$3)
           ...                                   ...
=IF('1'!B$18="","n/a",'1'!B$18) ...  =IF('1'!J$18="","n/a",'1'!J$18)

There are sixteen such blocks (actually 32, including adding weighting)
If I copy this array and paste 15 times (making 16 identical arrays, each of 144 cells = 2,304 cells).
So, for the second block, I want to do a global search and replace of the part of the formulae that calls up sub-worksheet 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 16 for each of the 16 blocks.
So, the string I am searching for is '1' - to be replaced by '2' for the second block - by '3' for the third block, and so on.
I expected to be able to do a search for '1' and set replace as '2' '3' ... etc.
I have done this kind of mass replacement of elements within a formula - but this does not seem to be possible anymore - not at least any method I have tried so far.
I have tried to do it without showing formulas and when showing formulas - but it makes no difference - I always get the same response:

We couldn't find anything to replace. Click Options for more ways to
search. This spreadsheet is not protected in any way.

Can anyone suggest a solution to replace '1' with (say) '9' in the above arrays of formulae?
I am running ms Office Home and Business 2019

Can you depict the Find&Replace dialogue?

Are you sure that the "Look in" option in CTRL-H matches your content type - Formulas?

Your question could be shortened to a single sentence only.

Could you try to create a new workbook with few formulas and try F&R?

It seems your formulas can be improved to avoid manual job. Use the INDIRECT function to build a reference to the sheet which name is provided in a cell.

Per rotabor's request, I tried to reproduce this error in the morning to share a screenshot and - well, it worked as expected!  I have no idea why it worked this morning and not last night.  The only thing that I can think of is that I did an update to Version 2410: October 28 - but I didn't see anything in the release notes that addressed the issue I was experiening last night.

Per Michal's comment, I copied text from the formula and pasted into [Find what:] box and [Look in:] was Formulas. Actually, that is the only option for [Look in:} - should I see other options in that pull-down?
